# What's the difference between "http://localhost/app/hello" and "http://localhost/app/hello/"?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, server

I have write a controller based on Spring MVC.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public class JsonController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public Person service(){
        Person person=new Person();
        person.setId(3);
        person.setName("666");
        return person;
}
```

When I access "http://localhost/app/hello",I get 404;
When I access "http://localhost/app/hello/", I get 202 OK.
What's the difference between "http://localhost/app/hello" and "http://localhost/app/hello/"?

Comment: Well the difference is that you mapped the `/` a the end to the function `service()` with `@RequestMapping(value="/",method=RequestMethod.GET)`, while the URL without the `/` at the end is mapped to nothing. If you call a url the rest api has nothing assigned to you will naturally get a 404.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

look your controller code

```
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public class JsonController
```

you controller have  url mapping -> "/hello"

and action(service) url mapping is "/"

```
@RequestMapping(value="/",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public Person service()
```

Now whenever we provided the mapping for our controller then every action of controller need the controller URL path as prefix (if URL mapping is defined in controller), as you have mentioned your **controller** mapping with **"/hello"** and action **service** url mapping with **"/"**
so when you need to access the **service** action then -> 
you need basepath of the controller (if Request URL mapping  define in the controller)  + action URL mapping

```
-> "/hello" + "/"   => "/hello/"
```

so in the case of  access URL "http://localhost/app/hello/" its easily find `service` action  and returned the response

Now when you trying to access URL "http://localhost/app/hello",   URL mapping search this mapping and find it in your controller mapping(because of its defined in your case) but there is no action defined for it that why are getting 404.

You can define it default action like:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public Person defaultAction() { 
----your code
}
```

so now if you will hit "http://localhost/app/hello" this your will return valid response not 404

Answer (score 1):

I guess, it is something to do with your tomcat redirect configuration. Try including the below attributes in your context.xml

**mapperContextRootRedirectEnabled**

**Desc:** If enabled, requests for a web application context root will be redirected (adding a trailing slash) if necessary by the Mapper rather than the default Servlet. This is more efficient but has the side effect of confirming that the context path exists. If not specified, the default value of true is used.

**mapperDirectoryRedirectEnabled**

**Desc:** If enabled, requests for a web application directory will be redirected (adding a trailing slash) if necessary by the Mapper rather than the default Servlet. This is more efficient but has the side effect of confirming that the directory is exists. If not specified, the default value of false is used.

Reference: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Context_Parameters